# Change Ratingbar numStars Programmatically giving issue in design

Tags: android, ratingbar

I want to change RatingBar start count based on API, but whenever I try to change numStars from Kotlin code it will create an issue in Ratingbar design (means half stars).
But if I change star count from XML then it's working fine. as shown in the below screenshot.

[image: half rating bar]

So I created a fresh project just for testing and I am facing the same problem. here is my code:

**activity_rating_bar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".RatingBarActivity">

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:rating="2"
        android:stepSize="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**RatingBarActivity.kt**

```
package com.mytest.myapplication

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_rating_bar.*

class RatingBarActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_rating_bar)

        ratingBar.numStars = 6
    }
}
```

Expected behavior should be full star will be filled.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. All you have to do is also set stepSize programmatically

```
ratingBar.numStars = 6
ratingBar.stepSize = 1.0f
```

After I added this everything worked fine for me.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add the rating value in float

```
package com.mytest.myapplication

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_rating_bar.*

class RatingBarActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_rating_bar)

        val ratingBar: RatingBar = findViewById(R.id.ratingBar) as RatingBar
        ratingBar.rating= 6f
    }
}
```

Comment: no no, i don't want to set rating, i want to change number of total visible stars.